# Facebook Unity SDK login rotation on iOS

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

My app was rejected by apple because of "cluttered UI." They didn't like that the facebook login popup was sideways (landscape game, portrait login screen) and the keyboard covers part of it.  Is there a way to correct the rotation issue?  Do we need to wait for another facebook unity package update?  I got a previous version approved without issue.  Maybe it's just luck if you sneak by the review board, unless the device is already logged in to facebook.

Comment: I don't think it's unity related. The Facebook app on iPhone doesn't support landscape mode, so the login will always be in portrait.

Comment: I see, so how should I appeal to Apple at this time?  Has anyone else dealt with a similar issue?  Should I just upload a new package and resubmit with my fingers crossed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed in Facebook sdk 6.2(now in beta).

Comment: I saw this after already fixing it myself, but I've marked you correct for posting.  Thanks